# How to create a after delete trigger for update table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to create a  trigger that update row from database.t_PMmessage  when a row from database.t_user is deleted.

```
create trigger [dbo].[deleteUser]
 on [dbo].[t_user]
     after delete
      as
        BEGIN 
            update t_PMmessage set receiverID_FK = null
            where receiverID_FK IN(SELECT deleted.userID FROM deleted)
        END
```

but I when delete from t_user , I get this error:
[image]

Comment: For your usage trigger is not necessary, rather add to constraint  `ON DELETE SET NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After delete trigger fires after the delete statement has been executed, hence the delete statement gets executed before the update statement in your proposed trigger and you get the foreign key constraint violation.

Instead trigger will fire instead of the delete statement you issue and will update the `t_PMmessage` first and then the delete statement.

Also use Exists operator instead of the IN operator.

You need an instead of delete trigger something like.....

```
create trigger [dbo].[deleteUser]
on [dbo].[t_user]
INSTEAD OF DELETE
as
BEGIN 

update t_PMmessage 
    set receiverID_FK = null
where EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM deleted 
              WHERE  deleted.userID  = t_PMmessage.receiverID_FK )

DELETE FROM [dbo].[t_user]
where EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM deleted 
              WHERE  deleted.userID  = [t_user].userID  )


END
```